# scrape text from a span tag containing nested span tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I searched a lot on google but was not able to get a perfect code line for this problem.

How to extract 55,000.00 from the given HTML code, using Python's BeautifulSoup Library.

```html
<span style="text-decoration: inherit; white-space: nowrap;">
<span class="currencyINR">
&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>
<span class="currencyINRFallback" style="display:none">
Rs. 
</span>
35,916.00
</span>
```

The above HTML code is a part of following link - https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B01671J2I6/ref=dp_olp_afts?ie=UTF8&condition=all&qid=1602348797&sr=1-19

I tried the following code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B01671J2I6/ref=dp_olp_afts? 
ie=UTF8&condition=all&qid=1602348797&sr=1-19"

HEADER = {'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
ppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.6"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADER)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
price = soup.find("span", {"style" : "text-decoration: inherit; white-space: 
nowrap;"}).getText()
print(price)
```

It gives me

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Comment: Sounds like `soup.find()` is not able to find the tag you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the url given in your question here's how you would get the price:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B01671J2I6/ref=dp_olp_afts?ie=UTF8&condition=all&qid=1602348797&sr=1-19/"

HEADER = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.6",
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADER)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
price_spans = soup.find_all("span", {"style": "text-decoration: inherit; white-space: nowrap;"})
print([p.getText(strip=True) for p in price_spans])
```

Output: `['Rs.35,916.00', 'Rs.35,916.00', 'Rs.45,000.00']`

Note: I've changed the `HTML` parser, so you might have to do this first `pip install html5lib`

Comment: sorry my bad use this link - https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B01671J2I6/ref=dp_olp_afts?ie=UTF8&condition=all&qid=1602348797&sr=1-19

Comment: i also want to extract other prices from the list.

Comment: i tried your code but it still gives me the error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text()'

Comment: If you find my answer useful, do up-vote and/or accept it.